# How to make images on Bitmap smaller?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I am trying to build a simple game on android and while setting the background image and other image assets on my main screen it is appearing too big as shown in the below image.

[image]

The actual size of the image is 1920x1080 and I want it to fit my screen like the image shown below:

[image]

The code for I have used is:

```
public class PoliceView extends View {

private Bitmap police;
private Bitmap background;
private Paint scorePaint = new Paint();
private Bitmap life[] = new Bitmap[2];

public PoliceView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    police = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.police);
    background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.gamebackground);
    

    scorePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    scorePaint.setTextSize(70);
    scorePaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    scorePaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    life[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.heart);
    life[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.brokenheart);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    //The order of draw matters as objects are drawn in this same order
    canvas.drawBitmap(background,0,0,null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(police, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawText("Score:",20, 60, scorePaint);
    //Three lives for the police
    canvas.drawBitmap(life[0],580, 10, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(life[0],680, 10, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(life[0],780, 10, null);
}}
```

How can I resize the images to fit the screen??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use this code for resize image

```
        Bitmap tmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPath);
        ResizeWidth = (int) (your size);
        ResizeHeight = (int) (your size);
    

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(ResizeWidth, ResizeHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);


    Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tmp, ResizeWidth, ResizeHeight, true);
    int leftOffset = 0;
    int topOffset = 0;
    canvas.drawBitmap(scaled, leftOffset, topOffset, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

[How to resize bitmap in canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35324552/how-to-resize-bitmap-in-canvas)

```
canvas.save();               // Save current canvas params (not only scale)
canvas.scale(scaleX, scaleY);
canvas.restore();            // Restore current canvas params
```

scale = 1.0f will draw the same visible size bitmap

Comment: I added it to the end of the code and put in the scale value as 1.0f but it still has not changed anything